# Fastest way to compare numbers in php

Tags: php, optimization

I have a loop that needs to run a few million times; 10,967,700 to be precise. Within it, I am doing some checks including:

Number 1 is less than Number 2
Number 1 is less than or equal to Number 3
Number 4 is greater than Number 5

I'm wondering if there is any optimization/tweaks I can perform to have these checks performed faster. Or is this a ridiculous questino?

Comment: We could give you some inputs for optimization if we would have the chances to see some code... Otherwise the common `>` `<` `===` (and so on) are probably the fastest and only compare elements. You could also experiment with the performance differences between if/else and switch/case.

Comment: Make sure the numbers are actually integers throughout and not string-representations. Should save a few cycles on type-juggling.

Comment: Great point Mike B. Everything is an integer in my case.

Comment: @godesign sample code: http://cl.ly/image/0U2d1V0y0k1y

Comment: @onassar thanks for the snippet. I would suggest you to chain your two if-statements to an if() {...} else if{..}. As well as using the for-loop instead of foreach.

Comment: When looping that many times, even loop micro-optimisations such as ++$I rather than $I++ are likely to make a difference... can you show your loop code?

Comment: For logic of this nature, you may save a lot of human hours by using the Logical Operators AND, OR, and NOT.  IMHO they're more readable, which could potentially save you a lot of time.  Again, IMHO, that is the great optimization.

Comment: @MarkBaker hope this helps: http://pastebin.com/rqTFVzCk

Comment: @godesign is the for loop faster than the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

According to your snippet I suggest you the following changes:

Use the `for`-loop instead of the `foreach` like this example:

```
$key = array_keys($aHash);
$size = sizeOf($key);
for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) $aHash[$key[$i]] .= "a";
```

This `foreach`-loop is 4.7x slower. (see the example at the end -  http://www.phpbench.com/)

`foreach($aHash as $key=>$val) $aHash[$key] .= "a";`

As well as checking a value is set the `empty()`-method is slightly faster than `isset()`.

Using the `if and elseif (using ===)` is also faster than `(==)`

I hope I could help you.

(Performance Source: http://www.phpbench.com/)

Comment: I'll give this a go, but I'm not sure how well it applies to the `for` loop I have setup. If you have an example using the variables, I'm all ears. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php informs that `foreach` structures ought only to be used with array and objcets